# Adding Menu Support to Custom Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating my first Wordpress theme and I am struggling with menu support:

**I added a custom menu in functions.php and implemented it into my header.php like shown below but the menu-option in the administration area does not show up!**

```
# functions.php

<?php

    add_theme_support( 'menus' );

    add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

    function register_my_menus() {
        register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
                'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' )
            )
        );
    }

?>

# header.php
# [...]
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
# [...]
```

My Setting:

- Wordpress Version 3.4.2
- MAMP Development Environment
- No plugins

Other information:

- The menu option shows up in other templates
- The menu is getting rendered correctly on the page

What am I missing here?

---

### Edit #1

I can't even see the menu option in the admin menu ([like here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gb6N.jpg))

Comment: Are you able to see the "Secondary Menu" dropdown on [Theme Locations](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/6/67/wp3menu-screen2.png) at menu dashboard?

Comment: No I don't see that. (I edited the question.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Few things - You don't need add_theme_support(); nor the add_action('init', 'register_my_menus')

Just straight up call the register_nav_menus function, like so:

```
register_nav_menus(
    array(
    'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
    'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' )
    )
);
```

Can also check if the function exists if you desire. But if it's only for use on your own theme and you know it exists it's not really needed.

```
if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh man... I named the file function.php instead of functions.php. Call me idiot -.-

Comment: actually you should use it with 
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Comment: Yes, so `register_nav_menus()` defines one or more **menu locations**. As long as you have at least one menu location defined, WordPress will allow you create **menus**, even though you are not required to link any of those menus to a menu location. I’m sure that design must have made sense to someone at the time (a long time ago).