# Create dynamic menu in wordpress theme converting from html to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have converted my one page html website to wordpress theme. `Index.html` page is converted to `header.php`, `index.php` and `footer.php` .

Now I want to make a dynamic menu. I have registered my menu in WordPress and it I showing in the admin panel. When I create a new menu now the page is showing to add my menu there. How can I create that page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Menu Support to Custom Wordpress Theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616166/adding-menu-support-to-custom-wordpress-theme)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to register the menu via functions.php.
If you dont have, create a file inside your theme as functions.php and paste the following code to register the menu.

```
register_nav_menus( array('my_nav' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'dz theme' ),
    'secondary' => __('Secondary Navigation', 'dz theme') 
    ));
```

And you can call your primary menu as :

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'my_nav' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: i have registered my menu in functions.php. I have to create menu while i have header.php and also have index.php which consist of all othere div sections which are not i header.

Comment: Is that you need to create a secondary menu? @ShahbazAmin